# Pasar query de SQL a Doctrine ORM

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine, doctrine2

Busco una alma caritativa que me ayude a pasar una query de SQL a Doctrine `(Doctrine_Query::create()->from...` no sé si es posible con esta estructura).

La query que necesito es la siguiente:

```
SELECT * FROM news, newetiqueta, etiquetas 
WHERE news.id = newetiqueta.id_news 
AND newetiqueta.id_etiqueta = etiquetas.id AND etiquetas.id = 5;
```

Hice bastantes pruebas, pero ninguna sin éxito. Un ejemplo es el siguiente (aunque probé alguna variación y tampoco me funcionó):

$q = Doctrine_Query::create()->from('News news')->from('Newetiqueta newetiqueta')->from('Etiquetas etiquetas')->where('news.id=?','newetiqueta.id_news')->andwhere('newetiqueta.id_etiqueta=?','etiquetas.id')->andwhere('etiquetas.id=?',$tag);

El ->execute() lo proceso más adelante después de unas comprobaciones.

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Comment: Hola Miquel, deberías indicar qué has intentado. Simplemente pedir que te resuelvan el problema no suele tener buena respuesta.

Comment: Hola ArianJM. Hice bastantes pruebas, pero ninguna sin éxito. Un ejemplo es el siguiente (aunque probé alguna variación y tampoco me funcionó):
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
->from('News news')
->from('Newetiqueta newetiqueta')
->from('Etiquetas etiquetas')
->where('news.id=?','newetiqueta.id_news')
->andwhere('newetiqueta.id_etiqueta=?','etiquetas.id_etiqueta')
->andwhere('etiquetas.id_etiqueta=?',$tag);

El ->execute() lo proceso más adelante después de unas comprobaciones.

Gracias.